# LinearLayout like gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

can we put images in LinearLayout one after one like

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

now waht happing is it going off the screen

```
1
2
3
```

---end screen--

```
 4
```

i want 4 shlould come to new column

i am creating image as

```
ts = new CircularImageView(getApplicationContext());

          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

          ts.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); LinearLayout.LayoutParams
          layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 150, 150);
          ts.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
          linearLayout2.addView(ts);
```

Comment: Sounds like you may want a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

Comment: Agree with Will ,Use GridLayout

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with LinearLayout, you can wrap 2 vertical LinearLayouts inside a horizontal LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_with="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ---Your images 1, 2, 3 go here ---   
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_with="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ---Your images 4, 5, 6 go here ---   
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Still seems like GridView will be a better choice. See this example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/